# Alterar o tamanho do botão

Tags: jquery, html

Estou a desenvolver um `footer` em **JQuery** que passei para este [***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/u2d9ttym/)

**HTML/JQuery**

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c" data-tap-toogle="false">
            <div data-role="navbar" data-grid="b">
                    <ul>
                       <li><button type="button" id="listSO_options">Opções</button></li>
                       <li><a class = "ui-btn-active  nav" href="#">menu</a></li>
                       <li><a class = "nav" href="#" id="listSO_btnDef" data-icon="gear">Definições</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
</div><!-- footer -->
```

Como se pode ver na área do resultado o primeiro elemento do `footer` que é um `button` fica com um tamanho relativo aos outros dois elementos mais pequeno.

Já tentei por o botão dentro de tags `<a></a>` mas estragou ainda mais o `footer`.

Eu estava a tentar fazer isto sem recorrer ao **CSS** e sem atribuir valores fixos de altura. É possível?

**UPDATE**

Tentei alterar o button para a como me sugeriram. Aqui está o [***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/u2d9ttym/1/)

**HTML/JQuery**

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c" data-tap-toogle="false">
            <div data-role="navbar" data-grid="b">
                    <ul>
                       <li><a id="listSO_options">Opções</a></li>
                       <li><a class = "ui-btn-active  nav" href="#">menu</a></li>
                       <li><a class = "nav" href="#" id="listSO_btnDef" data-icon="gear">Definições</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!-- footer -->
```

O problema é que agora esse elemento já não se comporta como botão, pois quando é clickado este continua seleccionado o segundo elemento deixa de estar. O objectivo de estar a usar o `button` em vez de `a` era mesmo esse. Deixar o segundo elemento seleccionado apesar de carregar no primeiro e activar as funcionalidades do primeiro

Comment: na documentação do jquery mobile ele especifica apenas a tag <a> como elemento  do footer, porque você não usa o <a> como button ? ele funciona da mesma forma

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues eu já tinha experimentado usar o <a> em vez de <button>. Apesar de ter ficado com o tamanho pretendido, agora esse elemento comporta-se como uma tab e não como um botão

Comment: eu ainda não entendi o que você esta pretendendo fazer, nesse exemplo o `<a>` function como um botão para disparar uma ação http://jsfiddle.net/kcpf4wuc/

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Cada um dos `<li>` vai despertar uma acção sim, mas como podes ver no teu **fiddle** que após clickares no "Opções", "menu" deixa de estar seleccionado e o "Opçoes" fica seleccionado. Eu estou a tentar fazer com que o "menu" continue seleccionado após clickar em "Opções"

Comment: entendi, porém não e boa pratica você fazer uma barra de navegação não se comportar como tal, para isso e melhor você adicionar um button fora da navegação mostrando que se trata das opções daquele menu, http://jsfiddle.net/kcpf4wuc/3/

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues e nem sequer é possivel adicionar pelo menos ao lado com a mesma altura e largura?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na versão 1.4.5 do jquery Mobile esse recurso funciona nativamente no framework, veja:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c" data-tap-toogle="false">
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <button id="item1" data-icon="bars">Item 1</button>
      </li>
      <li><a id="item2" href="#" data-icon="grid">Item 2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a id="item3" href="#" data-icon="gear">Item 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aconselhor atualizar, caso não seja possivel, compare as duas versões e veja o que modificou no `jquery.mobile.css` e adicione apenas aquilo que precisa.